# How to hide the action button in the headsup notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have added the actions in a notification using **addaction** in a notification builder, I need to hide the action button when the notification notify in the headsup mode and the action button only displayed when the notification expanded

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setContentTitle("Sample App")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setAction(action1)
                .setAction(action2)
                .setContentText(body);
```

Comment: Please Post your code

Comment: Please post some code and if possible then some snapshot also to make your question more meaningful.

Comment: I have set the notification priority to max so its display the heads-up notification with action button